# What is the difference between \begin{frame}{Some title} and \begin{frame}\frametitle{Some title}?

Tags: beamer

The question title pretty much says it all.

How is this

```
\begin{frame}{Some title}
    [contents]
\end{frame}
```

different from

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some title}
    [contents]
\end{frame}
```

in `beamer`?

My question is intentionally as general as it seems.
I would like to understand whether one should prefer one form to the other and, if that's the case, why / with what objectives in mind?
Or is it really only a matter of personal preferences?

Comment: With `\frametitle` you have a bit more possibilities, as you can for example use `\frametitle<1-3>{bla}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) mentioned in the comments, `\frametitle` offers you more options.

From this [Beamer User Guide](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) (page 73):

[image]